# how does PrimeFaces' AjaxStatus work?

Tags: ajax, primefaces

I am trying to understand PrimeFaces' AjaxStatus indicator.

There are two facets - start and complete.

Can anybody tell me, what really determines start and complete.

I am just trying to make the indicator GIF image visible when user clicks a button and make it disappear when he click another button.

If whatever I am trying to achieve does not make any sense, an explanation would be really helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

ajaxStatus component works with globally set components. This means that a commandButton with the attribute:

```
global="true"
```

will trigger a process that will make use of ajaxStatus component (will update it's output).
This said, ajaxStatus `start` facet will work when the listener method is called and will update when the `complete` status is reached, this is, when the lifecycle of the call ends.

As I understand, this will not take care of the success or failure of the process. For this statuses, you also have other facets available: `error` and `success`.

```
<p:ajaxStatus> 
    <f:facet name="prestart">
    <h:outputText value="Starting..." /> </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="error"> <h:outputText value="Error" />
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="success"> <h:outputText value="Success" />
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="default"> <h:outputText value="Idle" />
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="start"> <h:outputText value="Please Wait" />
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="complete"> <h:outputText value="Done" />
    </f:facet> 
</p:ajaxStatus>
```

There is an ajax loading gif bundled with PrimeFaces:

```
<h:graphicImage library="primefaces" name="jquery/ui/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif" />
```

Comment: 0 down vote
 

<h:graphicImage library="primefaces" name="jquery/ui/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif" /> does not appear to work with Primefaces 3.4

Comment: Please note that the error and success facets will never be visible when you define a complete facet. See the [tips section of the manual](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/components/ajaxstatus?id=tips).